# How can I load CSV data into an object array to be printed back to the user?

Tags: java, csv, readfile

How to load CSV data into an array of objects?

I've been trying to figure this out for ages now, and I'm really stuck. For context, I'm a first year uni student, and in my assignment, I have to use CSV data to generate statistics, and print it back to the user. In the assignment specifications, it says I have to load data from the file into an array of Project objects ("Project" is one of my classes). I've got to be honest, I don't really know what this means.

So pretty much, the CSV file comprises of data relating to projects in a country. I've got class fields for the "Project" object such as beneficiary, stage (e.g. ongoing, completed), and location. One of my tasks for the assignment is to generate statistics for a given province.

I don't really know how I can load the CSV data into an array of objects. I've looked up tutorials online, so I know how to create arrays and everything; I just don't know how I'm supposed to load CSV data into it, and then collect it and print it back to the user. I've collected code from the lecture slides, but all I know what to do with that is simply read all the data in the file and print it back to the user. So I've got that down, I just need to work on loading the data into an array of objects, and generate statistics for a given province.

Here is some sample data:

```
PROV_TERR_EN,BENEFICIARY_NAME_EN,BENEFICIARY_BAND_NBR,ASSET_CLASS_EN,PROJECT_NAME_EN,PROJECT_DESC_EN,PROJECT_STAGE_EN,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,COORD_SYS

Saskatchewan,All Nations Healing Hospital,9999,Health,Design and construction of a new community health facility.,Design and construction of a new community health facility.,Completed,50.761877,-103.787043,GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS

Quebec,First Nations of Quebec and Labrador Sustainable Development Institute,9999,Energy sustainability and connectivity,Comprehensive Community Planning,Comprehensive community
```

---

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int menuSelection;
        String region = null; 
        String path = "file_path"; // omitted for privacy
        
        readFile(path);
        

public static void readFile(String pFileName) { // Code from lecture slides; all I know how to do is print out all the data
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    int lineNum;
    String line;
    try {
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(pFileName);
        rdr        = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
        bufRdr     = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        lineNum    = 0;
        line       = bufRdr.readLine();
        String[] projectArray = new String[7];
        while(line != null) {
            lineNum++;
            processLine(line);
//            System.out.println(line);
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
                       
        }
            fileStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException errorDetails) {
        if(fileStream != null) {
            try {
                fileStream.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex2) { 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Error in fileProcessing: " + errorDetails.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void processLine(String csvRow) {
    String[] splitLine;
    splitLine = csvRow.split(",");
    int lineLength = splitLine.length;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitLine[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}


}
```

```
public class Project { // This is my Project class
    // Class Fields
    private String province;
    private String beneficiary;
    private int beneficiaryNum;
    private String assetClass;
    private String name;
    private String stage;
    private double location;
    
    // With Parameters Constructor
    public Project(String pProvince, String pBeneficiary, int pBeneficiaryNum, String pAssetClass, String pName, String pStage, double pLocation) {
        province = pProvince;
        beneficiary = pBeneficiary;
        beneficiaryNum = pBeneficiaryNum;
        assetClass = pAssetClass;
        name = pName;
        stage = pStage;
        location = pLocation;
    }
    
    // Copy Constructor
    public Project(Project pProject) {
        province = pProject.getProvince();
        beneficiary = pProject.getBeneficiary();
        beneficiaryNum = pProject.getBeneficiaryNum();
        assetClass = pProject.getAssetClass();
        name = pProject.getName();
        stage = pProject.getStage();
        location = pProject.getLocation();
    }
    
    // Default Constructor
    public Project() {
        province = "Province";
        beneficiary = "Beneficiary";
        beneficiaryNum = 12345678;
        assetClass = "Class";
        name = "Name";
        stage = "Stage";
        location = 00.00;
    }
    
    // Accessor Methods
    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }
    
    public String getBeneficiary() {
        return beneficiary;
    }
    
    public int getBeneficiaryNum() {
        return beneficiaryNum;
    }
    
    public String getAssetClass() {
        return assetClass;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    
    public double getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    
    // Mutator Methods
    public void setProvince(String pProvince) {
        province = pProvince;
    }
    
    public void setBeneficiary(String pBeneficiary) {
        beneficiary = pBeneficiary;
    }
    
    public void setBeneficiaryNum(int pBeneficiaryNum) {
        beneficiaryNum = pBeneficiaryNum;
    }
    
    public void setAssetClass(String pAssetClass) {
        assetClass = pAssetClass;
    }
    
    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }
    
    public void setStage(String pStage) {
        stage = pStage;
    }
    
    public void setLocation(double pLocation) {
        location = pLocation;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: An array has a fixed size which you assign when you declare the array. Assuming each line of the CSV file represents an array element, then the number of lines in the CSV file is the size of the array. Do you know how many lines are in the file (before you read it)? Can you use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) rather than an array? By the way, I suggest you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Did you try entering **[java] csv array** in the search box at the top of this webpage?

Comment: @Abra Unfortunately since we have not learnt List in the course yet, we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a favour to give `Project` the method `public static Project fromCsv(String line, String separatorPattern)` You can then use that in various contexts to get an instance from a csv line

Comment: powershell has a built-in tool called Import-Csv that does this.  You can read about it [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3).
Other scrpting languages may have such a tool.  
If you are forced to code your own tool in Java,  using an existing tool as a guide may help you with the design.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to count the lines in the file. Then you know what size array you require. You then need to read the file again in order to populate the array. Below is the code for class `Assignment`. I did not change the code for class `Project`.

Method `countLines` counts the number of lines in the file. Method `processFile` populates the array `projects` by calling method `processLine` for each line of the file. Note that method `processFile` does not process the first line of the file since that line contains headers and not data.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Assignment {
    private static int countFileLines(Path path) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            int count = 0;
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                count++;
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return count;
        }
    }

    private static void processFile(Path path, Project[] projects) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            boolean first = true;
            int index = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                }
                else {
                    projects[index++] = processLine(line);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Project processLine(String csvRow) {
        String[] fields = csvRow.split(",");
        Project project = null;
        if (fields.length == 7) {
            project = new Project(fields[0], // province
                                  fields[1], // beneficiary
                                  Integer.parseInt(fields[2]), // beneficiary num
                                  fields[3], // assets class
                                  fields[4], // name
                                  fields[5], // stage
                                  Double.parseDouble(fields[6])); // location
        }
        return project;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("datafile.csv");
            int count = countFileLines(path);
            Project[] projects = new Project[count];
            processFile(path, projects);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```